# Tap on floating context menu in appium

Tags: android, appium

I use appium to test my mobile app. Using [TouchAction](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html), I am able to get the appium driver to [long press](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html) on edittext to bring up the contextual menu that lets the user "Select All","Copy","Paste" text.

[image]

But now, I am not able to get the appium driver to tap on any of those options ["Select All","Copy","Paste"]. I tried to reference the options with the following, but that **didn't work**. Because the options are not of type ListView.

> WebElement optionListView =
>   driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ListView"));

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use(elements instead of element):

```
WebElement optionListView = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.ListView"));
```

After this, get the index of each keyword and perform "click" function on it.

Comment: optionListView turned up empty. I tried that, but the floating contextual menu is not a listview.